# Backlit keyboard setting not saved upon resuming from suspend

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-backlight

Upon resuming my laptop from suspend, the backlit keyboard will always be on at the dimmest setting, regardless of the setting when I suspended it. I am using Mint Cinammon, version 17.1.

After some digging, I found possible solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700069/keyboard-backlight-turns-on-after-lock-screen-display-on) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1510344). Unfortunately, they seem specific to Ubuntu. The most promising solution was proposed in post 46 and 47 of the second link:

```
 In the file:
 /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf
 change:
     <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
            send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
 to:
     <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
            send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
 and reboot.
```

Changing that value actually made my mouse stop working.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this that works with Mint?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you've listed works on Linux Mint 17.3.